I don't think you'll get all of the items at that shop
Suppose a couple buys their daily groceries from a nearby shop most of the time. One day the wife prepares a list of groceries to be bought for that day and asks her husband to get them on his way home (from work). The wife then continues:

I think you might not get all of the items at that shop.

I don't think you'll get all of the items at that shop.

I think you might not be able to get all of the items at that shop.

I don't think you'll be able to get all of the items at that shop.


Question: A native speaker of English told me that (3) and (4) sound clearer/more correct than (1) and (2). I wonder how just the addition of "be able to" can make (3) and (4) more precise than (1) and (2). Could you please explain this?

No, they are all fine. But we don't do find and correct here.

This is very subjective. Personally, I find (2) and (4) more natural - using 'I don't think' to introduce a possible problem.

I think that all four are fairly natural and normal and any perceived differences are tiny and subjective, and the 'native speaker of English' was being over-precise.

Do you want to know if they're clearer, more correct, or more precise?

@StuartF, I think if the meaning of a sentence is clear, it should be correct.

1.I think you might not get all ...
2.I don't think you'll get all ...
3.I think you might not be able to get all ...
4.I don't think you'll be able to get all ...
The four examples state respectively
1.possibility
2.possibility
3.possibility and ability
4.possibility and ability
From the context, the question is on possibility and ability, so examples 3 and 4 are clear.
As for 1 and 2, although there’re no mentions of ability (be able to), they are understood to include that and hence are similar to the other two. This is because there’re no indications that the man is unhappy with the shop. Hence any reason for him to visit other shops would likely be that of ability, that is, some of the items might be unavailable.
On the other hand, if there’re mentions of unhappiness with the shop, examples 1 and 2 may end with some reasons:
I think you might not get all ... [as some of the products in this shop cost more than elsewhere].
I don't think you'll get all ... [as some of the products in this shop cost more than elsewhere].

might not get vs. might not be able to get.
The phrase "might be able to" or "might not be able to" is proper and acceptable in written English.
Usages of "be able to".

Use this phrase to convey uncertainty about the possibility of doing something. (as used in OP's sentence )
Another use.
Consider the following example :
"I might not be able to come to your party"
is more polite refusal than.
"I might not come to your party."


I don't think "polite refusal" is relevant to the OP's specific context of a wife expressing doubt that her husband will be able to fulfill the shopping list at the local convenience store. In that context, it's potentially a bit contemptuous / insulting for the wife to pile it on with "don't think" and "be able to". After all, she probably knows perfectly well that some of the items she put on the list aren't available in their local shop, so she ought to just warn her husband about that right from the get-go. He might choose to go in other shops before getting back close to home.

And the wife might say "The shop might not have everything on the list."

@FumbleFingers I had given another sentence. In which it is applicable.

@FumbleFingers - I sometimes have nightmares about the world of made-up example sentences, in which men can't write a shopping list, cook food, clean houses, etc. Also they order their kids about an awful lot. This situation sounds like an example of a husband deploying 'strategic' or 'weaponised' incompetence. In those cases, I don't blame the wife for being 'contemptuous' or (oh dear!) 'insulting'.

@FumbleFingers, what is your opinion on (1) and (2)? Do they sound unclear to you too?

@Mr.X - this is a wife talking to her husband about going shopping. Don't you think that any tiny ambiguities would be very swiftly resolved?

@Mr.X -; There is nothing unclear about it. "be able to" is a standard phrase. The other example I have given (refusing an invitation), it's a polite way to say.
